# GROUP_CONCAT and Longtext

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat, longtext

I need to combine two text fields in the MySQL Database table into One, So I have used the Following SQL script to do it.

Table: tbl_newsitems
Combine: Need to combine the text in the 'ni_text' with the same 'news_id'
Table Layout:

[image: zNg6f]

Code used to combine the text:
    SELECT
    `news_id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`ni_text`
    SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM
    tbl_newsitems
    GROUP BY `news_id`;

But it won't display the full (Complete) text in the result section. The CONCAT field is trimmed and missing some text. The default Data type for the CONCAT field is TEXT (1024)

Result:

[image]

So how do I combine the whole text into one field without dropping the content. Please give me the script to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your create table statement and some example data on sqlfiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Answer (score 11):

To "fix" your `group_concat` issue, the server setting `group_concat_max_len` will need increased.

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

I believe you should be able to set it just for the session (current connection) without needing to change it globally/permanently on the server. Executing something like `SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` before your query should solve the issue.