# Create a new table with a column for every element in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops

I have create a table in MySQL where i have all the names of data I'm going to bring in from FRED data.

[image]

Now I want to make a new table, where the 1504 names in my example table above, each has one column.

```
AAA AAA10M AAAFFM ADBJORNS and so on.
```

So every name in fred_namecol should get one column each with numeric as value. Is there a easy way to do this instead of writing everyone manually?

Maybe there is a way too loop trough each name and make a column for them into a new table?

Comment: Bad idea.. MySQL has a max column limit in tables so it will fail with too many records if somebody provide a "solution"..  "MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table. The exact column limit depends on several factors: " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: You have a table with your users (1504 of them).  You want to keep on record a numerical value for each user right?  So just add a new column in your users table with a numerical type and store the number there.  No need for another table.  Do it at the row, not the column.  If your model forces such a setup, I contend that your model is wrong.

Comment: I will get 1504 columns, and the data is time series, so I will insert a date column later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a way.

In the following query; **replace** WRITE_YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE with the name of the table which contains *fred_namecol* column:

```
drop table if exists columns_over_1000;
set @prefix = 'CREATE TABLE columns_over_1000 (';
set @suffix = '\n);';
select @create_table_sql := concat(
    @prefix, 
        group_concat('\n    `', fred_namecol, '` INT'), 
    @suffix) 
from `WRITE_YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE`;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @create_table_sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

select * from columns_over_1000;
```

Comment: This code almost works i get the Idea, thanks but I get an error not sure why, 
    "ERROR Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual to your MySQL server version."

The error comes up at prepare  stmt1. 

But i get the idea, i get a text with all the column names.

Comment: @A.Salehi Yes, PREPARE is actually setting that text to a variable called stmt1 and executing it. 
You can remove the lines after and including PREPARE and simply copy and paste the generated sql from the results.

Comment: Is that all it says about the error? It is very brief to understand the reason. If not, could you please write the whole error here.

Comment: Yeah its, all it says. Weird cant find why, just copied straight from the code.
I tried to copy and paste the genereted SQL text but it wasnt all 1504 names from the list (I only get like first 52 names). I try copy row and all other options for copying, to copy it into a new script. When i open value in viewer samething, not all of them are there.

Comment: The Type is MEDIUMTEXT maybe thats why? I Found this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658760/group-concat-and-longtext"                         
       "I believe you should be able to set it just for the session (current connection) without needing to change it globally/permanently on the server. Executing something like SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000; before your query should solve the issue."
SOLVED NOW I CAN JUST COPY IT TO A NEW SCRIPT! THANKS FOR THE HELP!!